# Find the minimum of an expression.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, maxima-minima

$\begin{array}{l}Say\;x_1,x_2,x_3\in(0,1)\cup(1,+\infty)\\Find\;the\;minimum\;of\;the\;expression:\\E=\log_{x_1}\left(x_2x_3\right)+\log_{x_2}\left(x_1x_3\right)+\log_{x_3}\left(x_1x_2\right)\end{array}$

I literally don't have any idea.

Comment: $$\log(ab)=\log a+\log b$$ and $$\log_ab(\log_ba)=1$$ For $x>0, $ $$x+\dfrac1x\ge2$$

Comment: Take $x_1=a^{-1}, x_2=x_3=a^p$ with some positive $a\neq1$. Your function has the value $-2p+2(p-1)/p$, then, i.e. there is no minimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that $$\log_a b = {\log b\over \log a}$$

If we use arithmetic mean - geometric mean 
$$ {a_1+...+a_6 \over 6}\geq\sqrt[6]{a_1...a_6 } $$

**Suppose that all $x_i<1$ or all $x_i>1$**, then we get:

$$E=\log_{x_1}x_2 +\log_{x_1} x_3+\log_{x_2}x_1 +\log_{x_2}x_3+\log_{x_3}x_1+ \log_{x_1}x_2 \geq 6$$

---

If two of $x_i$ are $>1$ and one $<1$ (or vice versa) we get something like this:

If $x_1 = x_3=2$ and $0<x_3=x<1$ arbitrary we have:

$$ E = 2t+{2\over t}+2$$ where $t=\log _2x \in (-\infty ,0)$. So as $t\to -\infty$ we have $E\to -\infty$.

Comment: yup right, got it, thanks

Comment: That's true only for positive $a_i$.